# Are the 'english' values for event.key in any way international?

Tags: javascript

I want do some javascript validation.  I am using keyup and I've been going nicely with

```
isFinite(event.key)
```

I just noticed I'm not catching delete/backspace though so I thought I'd add a check.  Everywhere I look it says don't use the deprecated 'event.keyCode' (8 & 46) any more but the only easy alternative I can see is use

```
event.key ==="BackSpace" || event.key ==="Delete"
```

I just wondered if this is standard in just English speaking 'countries' (settings...), just for the same (european ?) alphabet or fairly international ?

Comment: I would suggest reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key.   It's standard and the same for every country.

Comment: whoops sorry I missed that.  Thanks.